# Magento 2 page messages not working

Tags: magento2

I am testing the sign up page using an email that is already registered and getting no error messages.

This is happening for the login page when using the wrong password, there is no error messages.

The page just refreshes and give no indication to an issue.

I have a Magento 2.1.6 site, does anybody have a solution to get the error messages to display.

Comment: check your log files and see the error.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain very well, sorry. I need to have frontend messages to display - e.g. 'that email address is already registered' or 'username or password are incorrec' - or something to that effect

Comment: please check javascript error in console. 
if there will be any javascript error then also page messages will not work.